# C++ UTF-8 Reading text file, counting characters and outputing results to another file. ‘ gets saved as nothing, but is counted. ā and € appears

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have a task in C++ to read from a UTF-8 text file, count the characters, and save the character + count in a tsv.

I use everywhere wstring, wifstream, and wofstream.
In the terminal, there are many empty spaces when checking everything, but when outputting to tsv everything is overall fine except for 3 things.

‘ when saved appears as nothing, but its amount is counted correctly.

From nowhere ā and € appear. They are counted as the same amount, but they are not present in the original text at all.

What might be the cause of these issues?

The code is a bit crude but looks like this currently

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <wchar_t> characters;
    vector <int> counter;
    string filename;
    string param;
    cout << "Please input the filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "Please, if you want to convert everything to lowercase, input 'lower', else input 'No': ";
    cin >> param;
    wifstream inFile;
    wofstream endFile("dancing_men_char_frequency.tsv");
    inFile.open(filename);
    wstring Tfile;
    int checker;
    //inFile >> Tfile;
    while(getline(inFile, Tfile)) {
    
        //wcout << Tfile;
        //sort(Tfile.begin(), Tfile.end());
        if(param == "lower"){
            transform(
                Tfile.begin(), Tfile.end(),
                Tfile.begin(),
            towlower);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Tfile.length(); i++){
    
            if(find(characters.begin(), characters.end(), Tfile[i]) != characters.end())
            {

                if(isblank(Tfile[i])){}else{
                    checker = 0;
                    while(characters[checker] != Tfile[i]){
                        checker++;
                    }
                    counter[checker] += 1;
                }

            }else{

                if(isblank(Tfile[i])){}else{
                    characters.push_back(Tfile[i]);
                    counter.push_back(1);
                }

            }
        }

    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++){

        wcout << characters[i] << " ";
        cout << counter[i] << " " << i << endl;
        sum += counter[i];
        endFile << characters[i] << '\t' << counter[i] << '\n';

    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    //wcout << Tfile;
    //sort(Tfile.begin(), Tfile.end());
    //wcout << Tfile;
    endFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ IO has no support for UTF-8. You'll have to roll your own, or use a third party library. There is also the [std::codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) class, but frankly I think you're better off doing it yourself.

Comment: "_I have a task in C++ to read from a UTF-8 text file, count the characters,_": That's already pretty much impossible without using some library made for unicode manipulation, like ICU, or limiting yourself to a subset of unicode. There is no support for separating characters in a unicode string in the C++ standard library. The C++ standard library is only aware of unicode up to the code point level at most.

Comment: What do you call a character? There are several incompatible definitions.

Comment: Are you counting bytes, Unicode code points, or grapheme clusters (user-perceived characters made up of multiple code points)?  Make sure you know the difference and clarify what you want.